# Remove new line characters from nested dataframe columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema

```
root
 |-- AppUsers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- UserName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BusinessLines: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Campaigns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessLineId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- StartDate: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EndDate: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Imported: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IsClosed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CampaignDomains: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- CampaignId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DomainId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- CampaignDomainEntityComments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- CampaignId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DomainId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EntityId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Comment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CampaignEntities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- CampaignId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EntityId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ClosedDate: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ClosedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CampaignDomainEntities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- DomainId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CampaignId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- EntityId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ValidationDate: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ValidatedBy: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Domains: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessLineId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Order: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Entities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BasesClient: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessLineId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Pole: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PoleCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PoleLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Transactions: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ELRId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ELRDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- UOId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- UODescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BusinessLine: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IsCampaign: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- GroupEntities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EntityId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GroupId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Indicators: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AccessLevel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CanBeCopied: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Definition: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ModeReporting: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameFR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Order: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Perimeter: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PeriodTypeEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PeriodTypeFR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- PeriodTypeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SubDomainId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- OversightIndicatorID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IndicatorEntities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- EntityId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IndicatorId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SubDomains: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Comment: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Order: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DomainId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SubIndicators: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IndicatorId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameFR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Order: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Unit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ValueListNameId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IsMandatory: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IsGDPR: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- OversightSubIndicatorID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueLists: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameFR: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Value: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ValueListNameId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ValueListNames: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameEN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- NameFR: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Comments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Definition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CommentValues: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- CampaignId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- CommentId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
```

Print of the dataframe :

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+
|AppUsers                              |BusinessLines|Campaigns|CampaignDomains|CampaignDomainEntityComments|CampaignEntities       |CampaignDomainEntities    |Domains                   |Entities                                                                                                                                                                                  |Groups                             |GroupEntities|Indicators                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |IndicatorEntities|SubDomains                        |SubIndicators                                                  |ValueLists                                                 |ValueListNames                       |Comments         |CommentValues   |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+
|[[1,null,JEROEN,SOMERS,JEROEN.SOMERS]]|[[1,PRIV]]   |null     |[[1,2]]        |[[122,1,9,add comments ]]   |[[1,1,2018-08-24,null]]|[[1,11,1,Draft,null,null]]|[[1,1,1,INCIDENTS,1,true]]|[[1,0071300000,Outil central (FORCE),1,SGPB MONACO GESTION PRIVEE,PRIV,000423,PRIV Monaco,Outil central (FORCE),true,0071300000,SOCIETE GENERALE PRIVATE BANKING (MONACO),20664,PRIV/MON]]|[[1,1,null,SGPB GROUPE,true,false]]|[[1,1]]      |[[18174,D3E_I1,EndUser,false,Rappel : les instructions transposées doivent être validées par la Conformité IBFS avant d'être soumises à la validation du Management de votre entité.,Flow,IBFS 000449 - IBFS Compliance Manual - published on 01/29/2015,IBFS 000449 - Manuel de conformité IBFS - publié le 29/01/2015,1,Global,Monthly,Mensuel,1,440,Complex,true,FCC.1.1]]|[[1,1]]          |[[1,18,null,Key Points,1,true,18]]|[[1,18.1,1,Entity,Entity,111,Text,,null,false,false,FCC.1.1.1]]|[[1,Discretionary management,Discretionary management,1,1]]|[[1,Compliance Item,Compliance Item]]|[[4,Priv-1,null]]|[[13,4,112323 ]]|
+--------------------------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

The Description in Indicators comes with newline characters and some unwanted characters like " , ;

I want to remove those unwanted characters from the description sub column and keep the structure as it is
I have done this with flat structure but nested structure seems to be confusing

To keep it simple i have removed most of the fields and kept only the ones on which i want to apply transformation

**Sample Input:**

```
{
  "AppUsers": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "UserName": "abc.bcd",
    }
  ],
  "Indicators": [
    {
      "Definition": "Rappel ;;;;; , \n",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "AppUsers": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "UserName": "abc.bcd",
    }
  ],
  "Indicators": [
    {

      "Definition": "Rappel",
    }
  ]
}
```

The unwanted characters has to be removed from Indicators.Definition column
Please help

Comment: please update with sample input data, and your expected output.

Comment: @RangaVure I have updated the sample Input and output

Comment: I think you have to write a UDF to handle target column to remove unwanted characters.

Comment: Can you print you example dataframe ?

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy way to unwrap/wrap your JSON. You need 1. to unwrap the Indicators field with explode and to create a new column with the value of Definition 2. apply the `;|\\s|,|\\\\n` filter to the new column 3. merge filtered column back to Indicators field 4. re-create the JSON again. This will constitute a huge overhead. I believe the most efficient way is apply the filter into raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to access your column , and use regexp_replace to remove unwanted characters. The following is an example.

```py
df = df.withColumn('Definition', regexp_replace(col('Indicators').getItem(4)), "/[~%&\\;:"',<>?#\s]/g",""))
```

Comment: I get this error message :
```
due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`Indicators`.`Definition`' is of array<string> type.;;
```